# Is there a way to hide/remove MyST-specific syntax so a regular Markdown parser can be used?

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, myst

I usually use ReST and Sphinx for generating documentation, but I'm dealing with a pre-existing Markdown system. I'd like to use MyST and Sphinx to generate documentation with references and autodoc, but make it available to the existing system as well. Is there a way to automatically strip out the MyST-specific syntax from the Markdown files?

I tried just rendering MyST syntax with a regular Markdown parser and the MyST-specific syntax was either treated as regular text or a code block.

Comment: No, not if you want to use autodoc. That feature does not exist in "regular" Markdown.

Comment: @StevePiercy That's why the ask is if there is a way to remove the Myst-specific syntax

Comment: No. If you want to use autodoc, you cannot use "regular" Markdown, and you must use MyST or reST.

Comment: @StevePiercy the ask is not how to use autodoc with regular Markdown, it is how to take MyST Markdown and strip out the MyST-specific syntax.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify what you want to achieve. Currently you say "I'd like to use MyST and Sphinx to generate documentation with references **and autodoc**, but make it available to the existing system as well."

Comment: To answer your intended question, no there is not. You would have to roll your own regular expressions to identify and remove MyST syntax.